# Формула LOOKUP возвращает некорректное значение (Google Sheets)

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, formula

Есть исходная таблица, там есть колонки

```
id | приз | место | статус пользователя
```

В этой исходной таблице id может дублироваться.

Есть финальная таблица

```
id  | статус пользователя
```

Там ID уже без повторений. Я импортировала из исходной таблицы их таким образом

```
=UNIQUE(IMPORTRANGE("ключ";"ПОБЕДИТЕЛИ (ВСЕ)!B2:B"))
```

Теперь нужно из исходной таблицы подтянуть в финальную статус пользователя.
Для этого использую

```
=LOOKUP(C2; 'ПОБЕДИТЕЛИ (ВСЕ)'!B$2:B; 'ПОБЕДИТЕЛИ (ВСЕ)'!G$2:G)
```

Где :

- C2 - это номер колонки в финальной таблице с ID
- 'ПОБЕДИТЕЛИ (ВСЕ)'!B$2:B - диапазон поиска по ID из исходной таблицы
- 'ПОБЕДИТЕЛИ (ВСЕ)'!G$2:G - диапазон, где должны браться ответ, из
  исходной таблицы (статус пользователя)

Значения возвращаются, но при ручной проверке на исходной таблице, выясняется, что они не соответствуют ID.
Т.е. если в исходной странице было

```
    ID  | статус пользователя
   1000 | активен
```

То в финальной появляется:

```
  ID  | статус пользователя
 1000 | без статуса
```

Из чего можно заключить, что LOOKUP возвращает неверное значение. Но я не могу понять, почему.

Comment: Я Вам в прошлом вопросе писал - показывайте ссылку. Намого проще, когда есть пример, а не круги в воздухе

Comment: если у него много разных статусов в длинной таблице, как вы определяете какой он статус возьмет?

Comment: Статус из другой таблицы тоже нужно тянуть с помощью *IMPORTRANGE*

Comment: Вот ссылка на таблицу: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lmSeKxtehIPRsAjTPsIvUrHhFHGFV4OPeiSEgLDc30M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно применяете функции.

`IMPORTRANGE` - для извлечения данных из другой *Google*-таблицы. Если таблицы расположены на соседних листах, функция лишняя:

```
=UNIQUE('Исходник'!B2:B)
```

`LOOKUP (ПРОСМОТР)` - поиск должен производиться в отсортированном диапазоне. У Вас же все *ID*  перемешаны. Поэтому:

--- или поиск производить по-другому:

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/('Исходник'!B$2:B=A2), 'Исходник'!E$2:E)
```

--- или применить функцию `VLOOKUP (ВПР)`

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Исходник'!B$2:E, 4,0)
```

Существенное различие этих решений: `LOOKUP (ПРОСМОТР)` найдет последнюю строку с искомым значением, `VLOOKUP (ВПР)` - первое вхождение.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ и комментарий!